# Monadic Parser in Prolog (Example DIMACS files)

Tags: parsing, prolog, lexer

Lets say we want to realize a monadic parser(*) in Prolog that only uses standard DCG and provides a lexer level and a parser level that work together. I would like to parse [DIMACS files](https://www.domagoj-babic.com/uploads/ResearchProjects/Spear/dimacs-cnf.pdf).

Simplification, parsing is not supposed to use backtracking or doing the lexing before the parsing, rather the stream can be directly read character by character during interleaved lexing and parsing.

Here is an example run:

```
?- current_input(S), read_dimacs(S, M).
p cnf 4 2
-1 -3 0
1 2 4 0
^D
M = (~_A+(~_B+0))*((_A+(_C+(_D+0)))*1)
```

How would one go about it and write such a thing in Prolog?

(*)
**Happy - 2.5. Monadic Parsers**
https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html

Answer (score -1):

A monadic lexer can be described as follows. The parser no longer reads a list
of tokens. Instead, it calls the lexical analysis function for each new token to be read. This has the benefit of eliminating the intermediate list of tokens.

To support a monadic lexer we defined the following DCG utilities for the lexer. The lexer assumes a stream S and a look-a-head character C in its first DCG input, and returns a stream and new look-a-head character. The DCG utilities are:

```
% current_code(-Integer, +Pair, -Pair)
current_code(C, S-C, S-C).

% next_code(+Pair, -Pair)
next_code(S-_, S-E) :- get_code(S, E).
```

The lexer is then readily written by using the previous utilities:

```
% read_token(-Term, +Pair, -Pair)
read_token(integer(T)) --> current_code(C), {0'0 =< C, C =< 0'9}, !,
    next_code, read_integer(L), {number_codes(T, [C|L])}.
read_token(integer(T)) --> current_code(0'-), !,
    next_code, read_integer(L), {number_codes(T, [0'-|L])}.
read_token(atom(T)) --> current_code(C), {0'a =< C, C =< 0'z}, !,
    next_code, read_atom(L), {atom_codes(T, [C|L])}.
read_token(T) --> current_code(0' ), !, next_code, read_token(T).
read_token(T) --> current_code(0'\n), !, next_code, read_token(T).
read_token(T) --> current_code(0'\r), !, next_code, read_token(T).
read_token(end_of_file) --> current_code(-1).
```

Now for the parser we use some separate DCG utilities. These utiltilites now
assume a different context. The context not only contains a stream S and a look-a-head character C, but also a look-a-head token:

```
% current_token(-Integer, +Triple, -Triple)
current_token(T, S-T-C, S-T-C).

% next_token(+Triple, -Triple)
next_token(S-_-C, R-T-E) :- read_token(T, S-C, R-E).
```

Here is some example code from the parser, reading a DIMACS clause:

```
% read_clause(+List, -Clause, +Triple, -Triple)
read_clause(_, 0) --> current_token(integer(0)), !,
   next_token.
read_clause(W, (V+L)) --> current_token(integer(N)),
   {make_variable(N, W, V)},
   next_token,
   read_clause(W, L).
```

The code is highly portable, only requires the ISO core standard get_code/2. It doesn't nead any reading of a stream into a list or somesuch. Here is an example run in SWI-Prolog. Warning! Needs a Prolog with good last call optimization and intermediate term garbage collection:

```
/* SWI-Prolog 8.3.21 */
?- current_input(S), read_dimacs(S, M).
p cnf 4 2
-1 -3 0
1 2 4 0
^D
M =  (~_7606+(~_7740+0))*((_7606+(_7750+(_8130+0)))*1).
```

Open Source:

**Monadic Parser in Prolog (Example DIMACS files)**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/7c71a2ae9ad7651b912f3920693438ad#file-dimacs-pl